# File as pygeoapi process input

Tags: file, process, upload

I try to build a test process that can read data from a file (just a text file containing "hello world" string).

I managed to make my process available at the process rest endpoint: `http://localhost:5000/processes/myprocess`

But I don't know how to pass my text file as an input parameter. I didn't find any examples.

This is my input metadata (myprocess.py) :

```
    'inputs': {
        'file': {
            'title': 'file',
            'description': 'what ever file',
            "schema": {
                "type": "string",
                "contentEncoding": "binary",
                "contentMediaType": "application/octet-stream"
            },
            'minOccurs': 1,
            'maxOccurs': 1,
            'metadata': None,
            'keywords': ['file']
        }
    },
```

This is the code that the process should execute (myprocess.py):

```
    def execute(self, data):

        mimetype = 'application/json'
        file= data.get('file', None)
        with open(file, mode='rb') as myfile:  # b is important -> binary
            fileContent = myfile.read()
        
        outputs = {
            'result': fileContent
        }

        return mimetype, outputs
```

This is another independent python script that calls my process:

```
    filePath=r'C:\dev\test.txt'
    url='http://localhost:5000/processes/myprocess/execution'

    with open(filePath, "rb") as text_file:

        data = {
                  "inputs": {
                    "file": text_file
                  }
                }

        r = requests.post(url, json=data)
        print(r.content)
```

I tried many ways and I either get an error message when converting my binary as JSON:

```
TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable
```

Or I get a 'missing parameters' message from the process (for instance if I try to base64 encode the binary)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet. So I'll try an answer, based on how I understand your problem.

You say to want to POST file contents, but in your example, your *execute()* function expects a filepath (not the file contents), opens and reads the file *on the server*, and then returns the file contents.

So actually, it is your *output* that is file content, not your *input*.

But you do return JSON, so it tries to convert your binary file content to JSON, and that's where it fails.

In case returning file contents is what you really want to do, check out this example:

```
'inputs': {
    'filepath': {
        'title': 'path to file on server',
        'description': 'what ever file',
        "schema": {
            "type": "string",
            "contentMediaType": "application/json"
        },
        'minOccurs': 1,
        'maxOccurs': 1,
        'metadata': None,
        'keywords': ['file']
    }
},
```

Then your code:

```
def execute(self, data):

    filepath= data.get('filepath', None)
    with open(filepath, mode='rb') as myfile:  # b is important -> binary
        # Here you try to open a file that sits on the server!
        fileContent = myfile.read()
        
    mimetype = 'multipart/related'
    return mimetype, fileContent
```

The mimetype is mentioned in the OGC spec, you may want to check this one out: https://docs.ogc.org/is/18-062r2/18-062r2.html#req_core_process-execute-sync-raw-value-multi

Calling it would be:

```
filePath=r'C:\dev\test.txt'
url='http://localhost:5000/processes/myprocess/execution'

data = {
   "inputs": {
        "filepath": 'C:\dev\test.txt'
   }
}

r = requests.post(url, json=data) # Here you post json data!
print(r.content)
```